# correct use of browser.waitForAngular after browser.get

Tags: cucumber, protractor

i am user cucumber with protractor and i have the following spec:

```
browseToAngularUrl: function (url, callback) {
browser.get('/#' + url)
  .then(function () {
    return browser.waitForAngular();
  })
  .then(callback);
```

},

but when i run the step it fails with 'true' as the error description

I tried the following alternatives:

```
browseToAngularUrl: function (url, callback) {
    browser.get('/#' + url)
      .then(browser.waitForAngular)
      .then(callback);
  },
```

and i get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:347
  return self.executeAsyncScript_(
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at runWaitForAngularScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:347:19)
    at Protractor.waitForAngular (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:353:10)
```

What am i doing wrong in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most calls from protractor, such as browser.get, already have wait for angular attached. Every time protractor sends a command, it waits for things like $http and $timeout to finish before resolving.

Are you sure waitForAngular is needed here?

Comment: Im actually trying to fix the code done by someone else so i will try to do it without the browser.waitForAngular. thank you! :)